# Is there a way to add same terms with different means in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

When attempting to add a new glossary term e.g. ABC it can have multiple meanings for different types. If I currently attempt to add ABC with different types, I get the message that a duplicate primary key cannot exist. Is there a way to add multiple terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only the term itself is key, the type is just a convenience grouping.

Comment: Not really. The glossary function is by design very simple, although I agree it would be more useful if the Type was also key. The alternative is to create a domain model to explain the relevant terms.

Comment: Thanks. I started off with a domain model but found didn't think there were limitations with the glossary. Is there a way to import the glossary as elements?

Comment: Not out of the box. You could copy/paste the glossary into Excel, and then use EA's CSV import.